# Store View Page showing 404 error in Wordpress Dokan

Tags: wordpress

i have installed wordpress and used Dokan Plugin for multi vender Module 
All working is perfect , but Store View Page Showing 404 Error 
so please help me in this issue

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is a problem with your permalink settings. You can follow this doc- https://wedevs.com/docs/dokan/common-questions/404-page-not-found-error to save the permalinks correctly. After saving the settings, just try to view the store template.

Thanks.